# Problem with persisting a child table JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a OneToMany relationship in MySQl and I mapped it using JPA. It works just fine when retrieving information from the database but I am having a problem when persisting the child table. 
[Picture of ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDsHs.png)

-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`course`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`course` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `descr` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`topic`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`topic` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `descr` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `course_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `course_id`),
  INDEX `fk_topic_course_idx` (`course_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_topic_course`
    FOREIGN KEY (`course_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`course` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;

@Entity
@Table(name = "course", schema = "mydb")
public class Course implements Serializable {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1886462862094528507L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "descr")
    private String descr;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course", fetch = FetchType.EAGER) //name of object in Topic entity  
    @JsonManagedReference
        private Set<Topic> topic; 
}


@Entity
@Table(name="topic", schema = "mydb")
public class Topic implements Serializable {


    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -365302645107748753L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "descr")
    private String descr;


    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="course_id") //name of the foreign key. Must pay attention here 
    @JsonBackReference
    private Course course;
}
```

I am trying to persist the child table by making post request using the following JSON. '`course_id`' is the `foreign key`, but I am getting an error.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name: "Java",
    "descr": "This topic goes over Java core",
    "course_id": 1
 }
```

> 2019-11-14 13:11:27.013 ERROR 18916 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause
>
> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'course_id' cannot be null

Comment: What is going on here? An entity, that is also a repository? I would strongly suggest reading about jpa at least a bit.

Comment: Andronicus, the @Repository annotations was just there by mistake. Thank you for suggestion and I removed it already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because you're using `@GeneratedValue` without additional specification. Hibernate by default will try to reach to sequence named `<schema-name>.hibernate-sequence`.

Since you're using mysql, you can annotate:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

This will result in hibernate using mysql's `AUTO_INCREMENT` instead of sequence.

You also need to define the column with `AUTO_INCREMENT` on schema creation.

You're also missing a referene to `Course` entity before persisting:

```
topic.setCourse(entityManager.getReference(Course.class, courseId));
```

`courseId` here is the `course_id` passed as json.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202409/discussion-on-answer-by-andronicus-problem-with-persisting-a-child-table-jpa).